# React.addons in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to use React.addons in React Native, as listed on https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/addons.html.

Especially React.addons.LinkedStateMixin?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, just make sure you use `react-with-addons.js` (or the minified version), and to the default `react.js`.

For example, if as seen in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robbiemccorkell/464482c178c3784df9c1), you can simply have the line 

`var React = require('react-native/addons');`

to include react-native with add ons.

Comment: But I'm using `var React = require('react-native');`

Comment: It doesn't work for me `var React = require('react-native/addons');` breaks the app.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `react` (open-source JS library dealing with the problems faced by web single-page app UI) and `react native` (open source framework that allows you to create native cross-platform mobile apps) are two different things, and that the `react-with-addons` are specifically to `react`, and therefore it is NOT supported by `react native`.

Comment: Now since react 0.14 addons are in separate repos, so it could possibly work.